# Special daily calendar for whole year needed

Tags: tikz-pgf, programming, calendar

I need to print out a special daily calendar sheet for every day of 2014. The solution here: [Page a day calendar problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69476/4736) no longer is available, the link to mattjy.me is dead. The whole daily sheet I need is displayed in the picture below, the two tables are easy to make.

But I do not know how to write the code which leads to a PDF with 365 (or even 366) pages, each page with the name of the day and the date, followed by two tables.

[image: Daily calender sheet]

»Mittwoch« is wednesday in German, »Januar« is January, of course. Don't bother to include exactly the tabulars, just take any tabular environment.

Comment: Have a look at the calendar library in the pgf manual. The following URL may also be helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91594/making-a-calendar-for-tug

Comment: Neither one provides a simple daily (one page per day) calendar, I've been searching for quite a time and not only for LaTeX, but as well for Excel.

Comment: Section 57 of the pgf manual shows how to loop through dates. Or you could use the datenumber package.

Comment: A very nice [TUGCalendar](http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/TeX-SX/12-13/TUGCalendar-Letter.pdf) by @Marc van Dongen and could not find the source code

Comment: @texenthusiast The sources depend on a proprietary font, which is why I didn't make them available as most people wouldn't be able to compile, would be wondering why, and would ask me lots of questions.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Is it possible to make a `source version which includes freely available fonts` as your answer to your Q or at TUG ?

Comment: @texenthusiast Sorry. Too much work:-( and it wouldn't look good anyway. If I have time I'll make the source available as is. FWIW I'm working on a calendar for 2014. I'll make sure to make the sources available.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen No worries:) at your leisure. may be 2014 will be good showcase for TiKZ tool at texample.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After all it took too much time, but pgfcalendar is a powerfull tool. This is the code:

```
\documentclass[pagesize, ngerman, fontsize=12pt, parskip=half, DIV=25,
BCOR=2cm]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{translator, babel, tikz, pgfcalendar, array, libertine}

\newcommand{\Tagtabelle}{
  \minisec{Fristen}
  \begin{tabular}{|@{}p{2cm}|p{0.45\textwidth}|p{0.25\textwidth}|p{2cm}|}\hline
   \textbf{Akten-Nr.} & \textbf{Angelegenheit} & \textbf{Frist} & \textbf{SB} \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
%      & & & \\\hline
%      & & & \\\hline
%      & & & \\\hline
  \end{tabular}

\minisec{Termine}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{2cm}p{2cm}p{5cm}p{5cm}c}\hline
 \textbf{Zeit} & \textbf{Akten-Nr.} & \textbf{Angelegenheit} & \textbf{Gericht/Ort/Raum} & \textbf{SB}\\\hline
 & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & \\\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\pgfcalendar{cal}{2014-01-01}{2014-12-31}
{%
\ifdate{workday}{%
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\LARGE\bfseries
\pgfcalendarweekdayname{\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday},
\pgfcalendarcurrentday{}. 
\pgfcalendarmonthname{\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth}
\pgfcalendarcurrentyear{}
}
\Tagtabelle

\pagebreak
}{}
 }



\end{document}
```