# How to put a variable as the argument of includesgraphics:

Tags: includegraphics

I am trying to create a calendar based on the first answer to this question:

[How to create  Page-a-Day Calendar Template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39972/how-to-create-page-a-day-calendar-template)

I want to have an image for each day, so I tried using a variable inside includesgraphic, but it does not work. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,landscape,a5paper]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{tikz}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf
\usetikzlibrary{calc}%
\usepackage{datatool}% http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\graphicspath{ {./Imagens/} }
\DTLloaddb{calendar}{falendario.csv}% Load page-calendar.csv into calendar DB
\pagestyle{empty}% Remove page headers/footers

\begin{document}
\sffamily% Default font family
\DTLforeach{calendar}
  {\calDia=Dia,
  \calMes=Mes,
  \calSemana=Semana,
  \calPalavra=Palavra,
  \calSignificado=Significado}
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    %\fill[black!80!green!25] 
      %(current page.north east) rectangle (current page.south west);% Outer frame
    %\shade [bottom color=black!70!green!25, top color=black!70!green!10]
      %($(current page.north east)+(-5mm,-5mm)$) rectangle ($(current page.south west)+(5mm,5mm)$); % Inner frame + shading
    \draw ($(current page.north west)+(5mm,-5mm)$)
      node[anchor=north west] {\scalebox{4}{\bfseries\color{black!65}\calDia\;de\;\calMes}};% Print YEAR
    \draw ($(current page.north east)+(-5mm,-5mm)$)
      node[anchor=north east] {\scalebox{3}{\bfseries\color{black!80}%
        \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}\raggedleft%
          \calSemana \par% Print WEEKDAY
          %\calDia~\calMes%print DAY + MONTH
        \end{minipage}}};
    \draw ($(current page.west)+(+60mm,0)$)
      node {\scalebox{2}{\color{black!95!green}%
        \begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
         \begin{flushleft}
            \large\textbf{\calPalavra} \par
            \normalsize\calSignificado% Print SAYING
         \end{flushleft}
        \end{minipage}}};
    \draw ($(current page.east)+(-50mm,0)$)
      node {\scalebox{2}{\color{black!95!green}%
        \begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\calPalavra}
        \end{minipage}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \newpage%
  }
\end{document}
```

Without the line

```
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\calPalavra}
```

it works just fine. But as it is right now, whenever I try to compile Texmaker will just start running and then stop, without giving me any error, and producing no pdf.

Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The argument to `\includegraphics` should be a file name. By the way, what’s the reason for scaling a minipage containing the image? Just do `\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{filename]`

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to put the scale. But the point is that my filename is different for every page, and I have 365 pages, so I am trying to use a variable as file name. Is it possible?